# How to execute chef cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra

In puppet you have `puppet apply /root/user-absent.pp`, what is an equivalent in chef?

Manual is really troublesome, It's just completely uninformative for me. Let's say I've cloned a repository from github, of some cookbook, what's next? how to execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [chef-apply](http://docs.opscode.com/ctl_chef_apply.html), which is new in Chef 11 and does the same. But in case you don't just want to run a single recipe, you should look at [chef-solo](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_solo.html).